# How to make http request and decode response to concrete type in Elm 0.17?

Tags: json, http, elm

I want to create a function that will make a request to the server and returns decoded value. I have custom headers within my request so I have to use [Http.send](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-http/3.0.1/Http#send) function.

So far I was able to create task

```
getCurrentUser userId authToken err ok =
  let
    request =
      Http.send defaultSettings
        { verb = "GET"
        , headers = [("X-Auth", authToken)]
        , url = "http://os.apiary.com"
        , body = empty
        }

  in
    Task.perform err ok request

type alias User = { name : String, age : Maybe Int }
userDecoder = object2 User ("name" := string) (maybe ("age" := int))
```

but I don't know where to put decode logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`fromJson`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-http/3.0.1/Http#fromJson):

```elm
getCurrentUser userId authToken err ok =
  let
    request =
      Http.send defaultSettings
        { verb = "GET"
        , headers = [("X-Auth", authToken)]
        , url = "http://os.apiary.com"
        , body = empty
        }

  in
    Http.fromJson userDecoder request
      |> Task.perform err ok
```

Comment: Awesome! thats exactly what I was looking for.